# Deleting lines in sheet based on text in one column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I currently have a macro set to delete lines I no longer need as a start:

```
Sub JSAidRun()
'
' JSAidRun Macro
'

'
Range("1:1,2:2").Select
Range("A2").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 17
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 18
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 19
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 20
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 25
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 26
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 27
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 28
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 29
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 31
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 32
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 33
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 34
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 35
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 36
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 37
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 38
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 39
Range("AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM").Select
Range("AM1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range("AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ").Select
Range("AJ1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range("AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG").Select
Range("AG1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range("AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD").Select
Range("AD1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA" _
    ).Select
Range("AA1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X" _
    ).Select
Range("X1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U" _
    ).Select
Range("U1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R" _
    ).Select
Range("R1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R,Q:Q,P:P,O:O" _
    ).Select
Range("O1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R,Q:Q,P:P,O:O,N:N,M:M,L:L" _
    ).Select
Range("L1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
Range( _
    "AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R,Q:Q,P:P,O:O,N:N,M:M,L:L,K:K,J:J,I:I" _
    ).Select
Range("I1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-2
Union(Range( _
    "G:G,AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R,Q:Q,P:P,O:O,N:N,M:M,L:L,K:K,J:J,I:I" _
    ), Columns("H:H")).Select
Range("G1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-4
Union(Range( _
    "G:G,E:E,AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R,Q:Q,P:P,O:O,N:N,M:M,L:L,K:K,J:J" _
    ), Range("I:I,H:H")).Select
Range("E1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-2
Union(Range( _
        "G:G,E:E,D:D,B:B,AP:AP,AO:AO,AM:AM,AL:AL,AJ:AJ,AI:AI,AH:AH,AG:AG,AE:AE,AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X    ,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T,S:S,R:R,Q:Q,P:P,O:O,N:N,M:M,L:L" _
    ), Range("K:K,J:J,I:I,H:H")).Select
Range("B1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("C4").Select
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 71.43
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter


End Sub
```

It's working nicely to pare down the amount of data from a report I get.

Now I need to delete more data after this. I am left with columns A-F, which is perfect. In column D, I need VBA to search for "Suspended", "Not Posted", "In Progress", "Expired", "Scheduled", "Unposted"...and then automatically delete any rows which contain that data.

I need this to all be run under a singular command if possible. I only want to run one macro.

Please help me.

I tried this as a start:

```
Sub DeleteRowswithSpecificText()
For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Suspended" Then
Cells(i, 4).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

but nothing happens

Comment: Change `If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Suspended" Then` to `Select Case Cells(i, 4).Value`, `Case "Suspended", "Not Posted", "In Progress", "Expired", "Scheduled", "Unposted"`, and `End If` to `End Select`.

Comment: How do I add this to my existing code?

Comment: That comment tells you which lines to change.

Comment: I fixed that part, now I changed the main part and it's bugging on the sheet name even though it matches 

Sub ModifyWorksheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ViewDetails")
    ' Delete rows 1 and 2
    ws.Rows("1:2").Delete

Comment: Check for trailing spaces.

Answer (score -1):

A little change on your code. Try this:

```
Sub DeleteRowswithSpecificText()
    '******************************************************
    ' Alert: it will looping all cells from the column "D".
    ' It's a good idea define the range just you'll use.
    '******************************************************

    ' Disable time waster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim Line As Range
    
    For Each Line In ActiveSheet.Columns.Range("D:D")
        
        ' Searching values
        Select Case Line.Value2
            
            ' Deleting row
            Case "Suspended", "Not Posted", "In Progress"
                Line.EntireRow.Delete
            
            ' Maybe you just want to change the cell background color
            Case "Expired", "Scheduled", "In Unposted"
                ' Change cell color
                Line.Interior.color = RGB(240, 107, 89) 'Red - Dec: 15756121
                
                ' Change entire row color
                Line.EntireRow.Interior.color = RGB(240, 107, 89) 'Red - Dec: 15756121
                
        End Select
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. You need to work through the Rows from the bottom up like the OP does. Also you are setting the entire Row to red which will result in bloating the Workbook, set just the used range of the row to the required colour.

Comment: OP didn't request for the cell background to be changed, so why does the answer propose it?